# Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, pdf.js

Using this part I can easily render any file :

```
LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
string script = String.Format("Sys.Application.add_load(function() {{ 
openWindow($get('{0}')); }});", lb.ClientID); ;
lb.ToolTip = "pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=kit.pdf";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "openPdfFile", 
script, true);
```

I am getting `base64` from database and can convert it further to `byte[]` or anything else. But how can I pass it to `'pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file='` string without any `JavaScript` converts like `uint8array`, `atob` etc.(And without saving)

Comment: use mime types and return your pdf file from the server.

Comment: base64 is wasteful conversion; URL length is often limited by browser, so shoving entire file will not work for large PDFs (>4-8k)